# Finding D matrix in LDU in matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

I have been searching the web for nearly 3 hours about a `MatLab` function that can take matrix `A` and give me back L, D, and U. Does such function exist in `MatLab`?

Please feel free to change the title of the question if you think it's not expressive enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be performed in Matlab as follows:

```
Given matrix A.

[L,U,P] = lu(A); % calculate partial-pivoted LU decomposition of A

D = diag(diag(U)); % get diagonal matrix

U = D\U; % the 'U' that is needed is really inv(D)*U
```

This allows you to write $LDU = PA$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab's `lu` function will find a LU decomposition of $A=LU$, then you can always write $U$ as $U=D\cdot \tilde U$ so $\tilde U$ has ones on the diagonal and $D$ is diagonal.

Comment: how can i get D out of U = D*H' thou?

Comment: If you have an upper diagonal matrix $U$ with non-zero values $d_1,d_2,\dots, d_n$ on the diagonal, define $D$ to be the diagonal matrix with $d_i$ on the diagonal and $\tilde U$ to be the matrix you get if you divide the $i$-th row of $U$ by $d_i$ (for all $i$). Now check that $D\tilde U = U$.